# Django display a dynamic json file content in template

Tags: json, django, django-templates

I have a json file on Django server

- The file content is **dynamically changing**
- I **don't** want to store the json data as Django model **in database**

My question is: is there a techinically low cost and efficient way to display the json content in Django template as a frontend webpage ?
All I need is display the json data in Django app web page

Comment: For that you need to share the view from where you are passing that json file content and the template where you rendering the json content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options, the one I recommend is to store your data in a json file inside your project, each time yo need to update your json file, could be through a signal if it is when you save some data, or in the time you need it.

Then in a view, read and throw to render your json file, this way, doesn't require so much processing, or touch the DB, it's like a cache file.

To write it:

```
with open(
    "path_to_file/your_file.json"), "w"
) as f:
    json.dump(your_dict_with_data, f)
```

To render

```
return HttpResponse(open("path_to_file/your_file.json", 'r'), content_type = 'application/json; charset=utf8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing some information here but any json object/python dictionary can be represented as a string, and there are plenty of ways to format it (For example, json.dumps() with the indent keyword argument). You could just store the string in the context object that's passed to the render function.